# InkCanvas in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8

I write handwriting application on Windows Phone 8(there is link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/convert-ink-to-text) but there is no InkCanvas in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pointer Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed) to detect the touch and move and in those events construct path and display it.